# Can generic RO filters be used with an AO Smith RO unit?

Tags: plumbing, water, plumbing-fixture, filter, water-filtration

I have an AO Smith 4000 reverse osmosis unit, and it is time to replace all of the filters (including the remineralizing filter). The AO Smith filters sold online seem a bit expensive so I was wondering if generic filters could be used instead.

Comment: I removed the "where to buy" portion because that's explicitly off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long they fit they will filter.
We don't do shopping here.

My minerals lasted more than 3 yr